# WPF Updating dynamic resource at runtime not working for a path inside a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface

I am having a problem with trying to change the color of a path inside a canvas at runtime. I use the canvas as a visual brush for the background of a button. I would like the user to be able to change the colors from a menu and have it update the application app wide. Think of it as a theme changer. Here's my code..

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ColorMain">#FF222222</SolidColorBrush>
```

Above is how I have my color defined and below you can see me use it as the stroke for the path in the **Sync_Background** canvas.

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="SyncBrush">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas x:Name="SyncButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
            <Canvas x:Name="Sync_Background" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="350">
                <Path Data="F1M0,200L350,200 350,0 0,0z" Fill="#FF55565D" Height="200" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="350"/>
                <Path Data="M355,205L5,205 5,5 355,5z" Height="210" Canvas.Left="-5" Stroke="{DynamicResource ColorMain}" StrokeThickness="10" Canvas.Top="-5" Width="360"/>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas x:Name="Sync_Layer" Height="92.935" Canvas.Left="110.823" Canvas.Top="20.532" Width="128.354">
                <Path Data="M6.599,38.127C16.446,19.891 35.729,7.5 57.908,7.5 81.062,7.5 101.062,21.004 110.461,40.567" Height="43.815" Canvas.Left="2.788" Stroke="#FFC1BFBF" StrokeThickness="15" Canvas.Top="-7.5" Width="117.222"/>
                <Path Data="F1M0,9.199L25.316,34.649 34.703,0z" Fill="#FFC1BFBF" Height="34.649" Canvas.Left="93.651" Canvas.Top="23.623" Width="34.703"/>
                <Path Data="M110.624,5.689C100.776,23.924 81.493,36.315 59.314,36.315 36.16,36.315 16.16,22.811 6.76,3.249" Height="43.814" Canvas.Left="8.344" Stroke="#FFC1BFBF" StrokeThickness="15" Canvas.Top="56.62" Width="117.223"/>
                <Path Data="F1M34.703,25.45L9.386,0 0,34.649z" Fill="#FFC1BFBF" Height="34.649" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="34.664" Width="34.703"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

Below is how I am trying to change the color at runtime. Where **Colors.Crimson** could be anything the user selects.

```
Application.Current.Resources["ColorMain"] = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Crimson);
InvalidateVisual();
```

Any thoughts? I was debugging and I noticed that inside the visual brush after I made the color change the path's stroke value was not being updated where as other things in my application were. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with it being nested in another canvas? The reason I'm doing this is because this is what gets spit out from blend when you import an Illustrator file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had very low success using `DynamicResource` inside `VisualBrush`. We had to put all the brush definitions (including all `VisualBrush`) into our resource file that gets reloaded when you change the theme. Replace the entire `ResourceDictionary` with your theme colors and brushes and fonts, not just one color in it. You can freeze your brushes that way. You can use `StaticResource` references in your `VisualBrush`. Somewhere in your control you can reference the `VisualBrush` using a `DynamicResource`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly. Currently you have to switch the colors for all your brushes and then reload the whole resource file?

Comment: Yes. I have separate resource files for each theme. I load the appropriate file when the user requests a theme change. I don't dynamically change colors on my brushes with the exception of the high-contrast theme, where the brushes are dynamically bound to system colors (and not frozen).